# Nuget build using jenkins and publishing in to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, nuget

How to build a nuget package in jenkins and publish the same in to the jfrog Artifactory?

Comment: We just use the [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference](NuGet command line tool) to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack](pack) the package from a nuspec-file and then [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push](push) it to Artifactory. The package-source URL should just be http://<server>:<port>/artifactory/api/nuget/<repositoryname>.